# Where is this endpoint request coming from?

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging

I am unit testing my latest piece of code and in the first test I create a new service. This gets as far as the default constructor which is:

```
public FooClient() {
        }
```

This is the last line of code run in the call stack before an InvalidOperationException is thrown.

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Foo.FooService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I have this endpoint configured and the service running but cannot figure out why it can't find it.

Comment: in your unit testing do you have mutiple projects ? some times you configure the endpoint in a certain App.config but is not in the config of the project that is set as Startup Project

Comment: I'm running the unit test from the test project.
The class I am calling is in the ProxyServices project, this is where the endpoint is located.

Comment: Paddy you need to configure the endpoint in the config of the test project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to configure the **endpoint** in the **config file** of the test project